# How to create a specific path in a maven archetype?

Tags: java, maven, tapestry

I want to make an Maven archetype with the following directory structure:

```
/src/main/java/com/example/myapp/pages
/src/main/java/com/example/myapp/components
/src/main/java/com/example/myapp/services
...
```

With

```
artifactId = com.example
groupId = myapp
```

Here is my archetype-metadata.xml :

```
<archetype-descriptor
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/archetype-descriptor-1.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        name="something">

    <requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="artifact">
            <defaultValue>${artifactId}</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
        <requiredProperty key="group">
            <defaultValue>${groupId}</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
    </requiredProperties>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet packaged="true">
            <directory>src/main/java/__group__/__artifact__/pages</directory>
        </fileSet>
</archetype-descriptor>
```

As a result of this the following is created:

```
/src/main/java/com.example/myapp/pages
```

I don't know how to get rid of the dot and make it a slash.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use [create-from-project](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html) may helpful

I made a example project in [github](https://github.com/alonWang/project-archetype) should be helpful